# Should a factory pattern be used to set state or type only

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

**Factory creating only correct type**

So here is an example of a `Factory` only returning the correct type:

```
public class BirdFactory
{
    public static IBird CreateBird(string birdType)
    {
        switch (birdType)
        {
            case "Eagle":
                return new Eagle();
            case "Penguin":
                return new Penguin();
        }
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
IBird bird = BirdFactory.CreateBird("eagle");
bird.FlyToLocation(new Location("London"));
```

**Factoring creating correct type and setting state**

Here is an example of a factory being used to set state and type:

```
public class BirdFactory
{
    public static IBird CreateBird(string birdType, Location locationToFlyTo)
    {
        switch (birdType)
        {
            case "Eagle":
                return new Eagle(locationToFlyTo);
            case "Penguin":
                return new Penguin(locationToFlyTo);
        }
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
IBird bird = BirdFactory.CreateBird("eagle", new Location("London"));
bird.FlyToLocation();
```

**The question**

How acceptable is the second practice?  Which is more maintainable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no cardinal rule that you cannot set state along with type in a factory pattern. And indeed combining patterns is an acceptable practice. So if you are pretty sure that the second method fits your needs perfectly, go for it.

I preffer method 1 over method two becuase it is less ambiguous.

```
IBird bird = BirdFactory.CreateBird("eagle", new Location("London"));
```

may lead a reader to think that the eagles "lives"(or was born) in London.

The next line:

```
bird.FlyToLocation();
```

will perplex them: "where is it flying to? Oh! You mean the bird has to fly to London?"

```
bird.FlyToLocation(new Location("London"));
```

avoids this ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

The first practice is better. In the second your are passing the location to the constructor and the location really has nothing to do with the bird. The location is for the FlyToLocation method and should be as close to that method call as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the complexity of initialisation required for the object. If it's just a single property then the complexity of the code you end up with is probably not worth it.

However I have incorporated the builder pattern with the factory pattern on occasions where I want some complex initialisation performed.

Answer (score 0):

Althought, as already said, there is no limit on what you can do, but keeping things simple and well-split responsibilities is key to as it's being called - good design.
So the factory method itself should be responsible only for creation of objects - in this case IBird instances, and if the implementation requires a location as well, I'd go on with some default location in factory, and wherever its going to be used - set the location afterwards. In this way you'll be able to modify the factory later on as well.
One example where you'll see this mechanism is flexible will be the following. Imagine you have the factory you've described - where the location is being passed in. What if tomorrow you decide to change the implementation of the IBird used, so it no more uses the location - you'lll need to modify the interface of the factory method, which will be a deal.

Regards,
Artak